# Angular6: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpService: (?)

Tags: angular

I am trying to read data from a web service using the HttpClientModule . I have created my own class HttpService where I want to do all the operations related to http.
However, I am getting an error when creating the HttpService object.

Code in my main class:

```
httpS:HttpService;
this.httpS.getHttpData(this.urlS).subscribe(data => {
this.posts = data
});
```

HttpService class:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Post } from '../Interfaces/Post';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class HttpService {

constructor(private httpC: HttpClient) { }

getHttpData(urlString: string): Observable<Post[]> {
  console.log(urlString);
  return this.httpC.get<Post[]>(urlString);
}
}
```

AppModule.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpService } from './classes/HttpService';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Would be very grateful for everyone who can help me with this problem :)

Comment: first of all your service should be marked with `Injectable` decorator, secondly you need to inject that service to your component. That I notice on first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `@Injectable()` to your `HttpService`, since you are using  `Dependency Injection` (HttpClient) in your service

```
@Injectable()

export class HttpService {

constructor(private httpC: HttpClient) { }

getHttpData(urlString: string): Observable<Post[]> {
  console.log(urlString);
  return this.httpC.get<Post[]>(urlString);
}
}
```

EDIT :

Well, as @ AJT_82 pointed out, You should add `HttpService` as a DI in your component, instead of creating a direct reference `httpS:HttpService`.

Add this to your component

```
constructor (private httpS : HttpService) { 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Incectables (very new to Angular). It's working now!